# Nothing will boot after December 10 update (14.10, dual boot)

Tags: 14.10

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10, dual booted with Windows 8.1. I have an Acer Aspire V5-5520. After today's update (it might be the December 11th update since I did both today), I was prompted to restart the computer. When it came back on, and every time I've tried to boot it since, all I see is the Acer screen, which soon goes black like it wants to bring up the prompt asking whether I want to go into Ubuntu or Windows. But that doesn't come up, and instead I get the Acer screen again. Also, another big problem: holding Shift at startup does nothing, and pressing any F# button does nothing. So it looks like a Gameboy with no cartridge.

I'm not very tech-savvy, so I'm sorry if any of that was confusing. I haven't tried booting with a live-USB, but I can't access the BIOS/UEFI anyway. Does anybody know what's wrong, how I can fix it, and whether or not my files are safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the BIOS/UEFI shell, try the <kbd>Del</kbd> key. Just try it once...

Now for your crashed system...
Your system has lost the entry of [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) from [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). This must be the case as per your description I'm guessing...So to resolve this you just need to restore your GRUB.

For that goto [Howto Fix Grub](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/Howto_Fix_Grub) or [How to Reinstall Grub Onto Your MBR](http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/grub-reinstall.htm) or [HOWTO: Restore GRUB (if your MBR is messed up)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24113&s=f0ce9da1adad75aa9a5b229984be206c) whichever you might find easier.

Comment: DEL doesn't work either. Same thing happens. Those links will come in handy once I can figure out how to get into the BIOS/UEFI, so thanks. But nothing yet.

Comment: To get into BIOS/UEFI, when you start (press power button/LED), just start pressing F2, F12, DEL simultaneously...that will definitely lead you to the BIOS/UEFI. Try this once. DO NOT WAIT FOR ACER name TO APEAR.

Comment: That didn't work. I tried holding it down, pressing it once, pressing it lots, and holding it down before I turned it on.

Comment: I tried again and it worked (after, like, the tenth try). I have no idea what changed, but I did nothing differently. So, uh... thanks!

Comment: No need to hold it, simultaneous pressing is more important as we're trying to force MOBO to execute our command before executing BIOS further. Still doesn't work then may be you need to consult some Technician guy.